# Trying to solve the "undefined method 'xxx' for class Syck::DomainType" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger, delayed-job

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, RVM (Ruby Version Manager) running Ruby 1.9.2, Phusion Passenger 3 and the DelayedJob gem. As many people, I am getting the `undefined method 'xxx' for class Syck::DomainType`.

I read both [Delayed Jobs Common problems](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-undefined_method_xxx_for_class) and [Phusion Passenger & running multiple Ruby versions](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/) but I am still in trouble with the mentioned error. In particular, the [first article](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-undefined_method_xxx_for_class) says:

> It can also happen when using the standard Passenger/RVM setup_load_paths.rb as detailed on the RVM setup pages: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/ To solve this, simply delete that file.

However, I do not have that file in My Ruby on Rails project... **how can I solve the problem?**

---

*Note I*: I am not using Thin but Apache/Passenger.

*Note II*: Looking closely at the 'handler' field of the delayed job database table it seems to be all correct:

```
| --- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer 
args: 
- !ruby/ActiveRecord:User 
  attributes: 
    id: 2
    ...
    created_at: 2011-08-09 15:05:38 Z
    updated_at: 2012-01-19 03:44:46 Z
method_name: :confirm_pending_password
object: !ruby/class Users::Mailer
```

Comment: psych and syck are not compatible, yaml generated by one will not be read by second, make sure you read/write using the same yaml backend